# Python matplotlib plot /graph partial refresh from starting point

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Sorry I am a bit new to python and matplotlib so I dont know if I am asking it correctly. As of now I am plotting graphs where I collect an array of integers coming via serial port and refreshing the whole plot area at once. Now I want to do partial refresh (idk if it is the correct word) something like a PPG/ECG trace where once the line/trace reaches the end of plot area it starts from beginning, something like in the example here
[1]: http://theblogofpeterchen.blogspot.com/2015/02/html5-high-performance-real-time.html.
I do understand that if I keep on appending the serial port data and plotting it as soon as it arrives will keep on extending the plot forward but I have no clue how to return back at the the beginning point and redraw it gradually as in ECG.

Kindly help in this regard

Thank you

Comment: Pls provide MCVE and toy example data, and I think matplotlib animation can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution below using `FuncAnimation`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram


ecg = electrocardiogram()[0:1000]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], '-')

# this is repeat length
n = 200


def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, n)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 2)
    return ln,

def update(i):
    # update xlim of axes
    if i % n == 0:
        ln.axes.set_xlim(int(i/n)*n, int(i/n)*n+n)
    else:
        xdata.append(i)
        ydata.append(ecg[i])
        ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=1000, init_func=init, blit=True, interval=10, repeat=False)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for helping. Your example helps a lot but it also clears the plot once the trace reaches the right side extreme of plot area which is not desirable whereas the demo in the  link http://theblogofpeterchen.blogspot.com/2015/02/html5-high-performance-real-time.html  clears and updates ordinates corresponding to abscissa. I don't know if I am explaining it correctly. Kindly play the demo in the link

Comment: You are strongly encouraged to get things better based on my code provided, not just asking for a full solution, This is not how SO works. If you dont think this is a solution, it's totally fine NOT to accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I was going to accept it but waiting for some  more help ;)